# How to access and use index of each item inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table where the last column in each row contains a little loading icon which I would like to display when a button inside the table is clicked.

When each table row is generated with ng-repeat, the loader shows up in every row rather than the individual one. How can I set ng-show to true or false for only the current index clicked?

Template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
  <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
  <td><a ng-click="someAction(record.name)">Some Action</a></td>
  <td ng-show="loading">Loading...</td>
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.someAction = function(recordName) {
  $scope.loading = true;
};
```

Comment: Hy i have an issue this is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253719/angularjs-update-template-var-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass in the `$index` parameter and set/use the corresponding index. `$index` is automatically available in the scope of an `ng-repeat`.

```
<td><a ng-click="someAction(record.name, $index)">Some Action</a></td>
<td ng-show="loading[$index]">Loading...</td>


$scope.someAction = function(recordName, $index) {
  $scope.loading[$index] = true;
};
```

Here's a generic sample with all the logic in the view for convenience: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AzifiFa/12/edit)**

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in ['a','b','c']" ng-init="loading=[]">
  <p ng-click="loading[$index]=true">Click me! Item Value: {{foo}}<p>
  <p ng-show="loading[$index]">Item {{$index}} loading...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's passing in the index fine, but when it hits `$scope.loading[$index] = true` I'm getting `Cannot set property '1' of undefined`

Comment: @greg because you need to make `$scope.loading` an array. See my generic sample. I just initialized it as an array right in the view. Otherwise, go in your controller and put `$scope.loading = []` so that you have a place to store the flags.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to handle this.

The problem here is that your variable loading is sharing the scope between the rows.

One approach could be use [$index](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-index-event-log)

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
    <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="someAction(record.name, $index)">Some Action</a></td>
    <td ng-show="loading">Loading...</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.someAction = function(recordName, $index) {
    $scope.loading[$index] = true;
};
```

Using a property in your object record:

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
    <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="someAction(record)">Some Action</a></td>
    <td ng-show="record.loading">Loading...</td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.someAction = function(record) {
   var name = record.name; 
   record.loading = true;
};
```

Best regards

Comment: Couldn't get the first approach working, but the second approach works great. Thanks!

Comment: @greg I really recommend you figure out how to use `$index`. I don't mind answering more questions about it. You shouldn't be adding a property to your data like this. That will probably eventually cause more problems. Imagine if you need to save `records` to the database - now each item has properties that associate it with the view and therefore need to be removed. Keep your view and model concerns separate.

Answer (score 0):

The scope inside ng-repeat is different form the one outside. Actually the scope outside ng-repeat is the parent of the one inside. So the html code goes here

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
    <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="someAction(record)">Some Action</a></td>
    <td ng-show="$parent.loading">Loading...</td>
</tr>
```